# What is the purpose of Default Field on Process Input of Salesforce CPQ?

Tags: cpq

I want to use the Guided Selling on CPQ and on one of the questions, I want to show a default value as the answer.
Does the `Default Field` serves for this purpose?
I tried with an example but nothing changes.

From Salesforce the explanation of Default Field is:

> Quote field that sources default value for this input.

[image: Default Filed CPQ]

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Enrik

Comment: What value you are going to use on Default field? Need more clarification on your issue.

Comment: I choose a Quote field on that, to show the default value from it.

Comment: Did you set default value while creating field? I believe you have created custom field named Default Field.

Comment: I bit confused.. do you want show some message on this object ?

Comment: I updated the image for better understanding. The image is the part when I try to create a new Process Input on Quote Process and I want to know the use of Default Field on it.

Comment: I just want to confirm, that you didn't create this field and what is the object name?
 looks like it's custom object.

Comment: @PremAnandh as I have mentioned, I'm on Salesforce CPQ, which is a Managed Package installed, and I need some insights from one who have experience on CPQ..

Answer (score 0):

don't know if you still need an answer
In guided selling you can take as default a value which is already choosen on the quote object. Just add the API name as a picklist value to this field and it will show always the value of the quote as default